# How do I click on a button that has no ID or HTML using Python Selenium?

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, selenium

I have a script written and have been able to code for buttons that have html but this button that I inspected on this link, doesn't have one.

This is the element for the login button.

```
<input type="submit" value="login" class="button">
```

How would I write this line of script to click on this button using selenium & python?

Comment: Try to use [CSS selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) or [XPath](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To click on the button with text as **Login** you can use the following line of code :

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//form[@method='post' and @action='/auth/login/']//input[@class='button' and @value='login']").click()
#or
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//form[@method='post' and @action='/auth/login/']//input[@class='button' and @value='login']").submit()
```

Answer (score 0):

your element has few attributes, which we can use. Try to find an element which starts with input and has an attribute type='submit'

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='content']//input[@type='submit']").click()
```

Comment: Note that there are two Auth forms with two Submit buttons - the first one is hidden, so your code will not work!

Comment: Hmm I tried it and it didn;t work. I got this in return for the string on CMD

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class='button-status-container']/button[@type='submit']"}

Comment: @OtakuWiz , `//div[@class='button-status-container']/button[@type='submit']`? But suggested XPath is totally different

Comment: @OtakuWiz it's another error which you got in your tests. this doesn't apply to this section of code

Comment: Yes, you are right! I had left a string in that needed to be removed. it works now! omg, I thought I would never get it to work. Thank you so much!